# What is the value of $g(z)$ when $|z|>3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's the full problem:

> Let C be the circle $|z|=3$, described in the positive sense. Show that if
>   $$g(z)=\int_{C} \frac{2s^2-s-2}{s-z}ds \;\;\;\;\;\;(|z|\neq 3)$$
>   then $g(2)=8\pi i$. What is the value of $g(z)$ when $|z|>3$.

Okay, so I was able to figure out the first part by simply using Cauchy's Integral Formula and I know that the second part entails that $g(z)=0$ by the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem. I just have a few questions as I really don't understand this problem.

Since we are given $C \mathbb{\;is\;} |z|=3$, I'm assuming this $C$ is changing when we have $|z|\neq 3$ and $|z|>3$? Or, for when we have part $|z|\neq 3$, is that just talking about the values in which we can plug into $\int_{C} \frac{2s^2-s-2}{s-z}ds$ for $z$? Like, $|z|\neq 3 \implies z \in (-3,3)$.

Silly questions I know, I just hoping for some clearing up. Especially for $|z|>3$. If anyone could help, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Bad notation using $z$ for two different things. It would have been better to say "$C$ is the circle $\lvert s\rvert = 3$", since $s$ is the variable of integration, or to use an altogether different letter, e.g. "$C$ is the circle $\lvert w\rvert = 3$". The circle $C$ is fixed. The integral $$\int_C \frac{2s^2 - s - 2}{s-z}\,ds$$ exists only for $\lvert z\rvert \neq 3$, since the integrand would have a pole on the contour for $\lvert z\rvert = 3$.

Comment: C is the circle with radius 3, and not changing.$|z|\neq 3$ determines where g is defined.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah the book I'm using can be pretty iffy with some of the problems it presents. Okay so, C is unchanging. That means that we're analytic within C, and we know that the singularity in not contained within. But why do we end up having a singularity on C at |z|=3?

Comment: For $\lvert z\rvert = 3$, you get a pole of the integrand at $s = z$. That's not integrable. So $g(z)$ isn't defined for $\lvert z\rvert = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> Will you have poles within your contour if $|z|>3$?

Comment: Did you read the question? Or only the quoted problem? (The answer to which the OP already knows.)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Let's wait for the response of the OP to this answer. We do not have to rush! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Since our contour is C (|z|=3), we will not not have any singularity contained within. However, the question remains as to why C is not analytic along the disk. :|